# Amazon S3 Jenkins Plugin - Java 8 Update 60

Tags: amazon-s3, jenkins-plugins

I'm using S3 Publisher Plugin to upload some backups to my bucket. I've recently updated the Java version in my mac to Java 8 Update 60 and I keep getting this error:

```
Can't connect to S3 service: AWS authentication requires a valid Date or x-amz-date header (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just encountered the same issue, and found out that this is [Bug #444 of aws-sdk-java](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/444) wich was triggered by a bug in [Joda Time](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/issues/288).

The current *s3-plugin* is using an *aws-sdk-java* version that should not be affected by the *JodaTime* issue on java 8, but it is possible that an older *JodaTime* version is used because of a dependency in Jenkins itself (not the s3-plugin).

For the moment, I downgraded to using Java 7 to start the slave, but using java 8 for building.

Comment: Thanks maybe I will try to downgrade

Answer (score 0):

I've manage to add in the job the s3cmd using the envinject plugin over the build environment configuration like this:

[image: Configure Jenkins job]